# Overwrite CSS filter invert not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I'm writing small firefox add-on for comfortable reading pages at night. It should invert page colors but do not invert images.
The code is:

```
document.body.style.filter = "invert(100%)";

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].style.removeProperty("filter"); // NOT WORKING
    imgs[i].style.filter = "invert(0%)";    // NOT WORKING EITHER
}
```

The problem is that it does not work as expected - the images still inverted, thouth inspect element inside firefox shows they have proper invert(0%) style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you invert the body that means *all* its contents are inverted. To display images in their original colors you need to *invert them again*, i.e. apply `invert(100%)` to them.

Note that this is different from CSS inheritance, filters conceptually apply when compositing the pixels of the box onto its parent, the images are inside the `<body>` box, that's why they get inverted too.

Small sidenote: You may want to apply it to the `document.documentElement` or `:root` selector – in most cases that's the `<html>` node – since bodies can be smaller than the viewport. Another thing to consider are frames nested inside inverted documents.

Comment: Sir, applying invert(100%) to images does what i need! Thank you!